# Update Node.js Passport User

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, passport.js, passport-local

A Node.js / Express app with MongoDB, and using Passport, Passport Local and Passport Local Mongoose.

I'm trying allow registered users of my site to update their profiles. My idea was to rehash the signup form and logic, and send the updated data via a PUT request to the server.

The signup uses Ajax to submit the form, and whilst that works OK, when I send a PUT request to update the user, `req.body` comes back empty and the server throws out an error 500.

The update-form markup and javascript are nearly identical to the signup, so is it because I'm using a PUT request? I'm not even sure if I'm going about this in the right way...

Any pointers would be very happily received!

Edit user form submit logic:

```
    $form.on('submit', function(e) {
      if ($form.hasClass('is-uploading')) return false;

      $form.addClass('is-uploading').removeClass('is-error');

      if (isAdvancedUpload) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var ajaxData = new FormData($form.get(0));

        if (droppedFiles) {
          $.each(droppedFiles, function(i, file) {
            ajaxData.append($input.attr('name'), file);
          });
        }

        $.ajax({
          url: $form.attr('action'),
          type: $form.attr('method'),
          // data: ajaxData,
          dataType: 'json',
          cache: false,
          contentType: false,
          processData: false,
          complete: function() {
            $form.removeClass('is-uploading');
          },
          success: function(data) {
            // $form.addClass(data.success == true ? 'is-success' : 'is-error');
            // if (!data.success) console.log(data);
            window.location.replace('/matches');
          },
          error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(xhr)
            console.log(xhr.statusText);
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(errorThrown);          }
        });

      } else {
        var iframeName = 'uploadiframe' + new Date().getTime();
        $iframe = $('<iframe name="' + iframeName + '" style="display: none;"></iframe>');

        $('body').append($iframe);
        $form.attr('target', iframeName);

        $iframe.one('load', function() {
          var data = JSON.parse($iframe.contents().find('body').text());
          $form
            .removeClass('is-uploading')
            .addClass(data.success == true ? 'is-success' : 'is-error')
            .removeAttr('target');
          if (!data.success) $errorMsg.text(data.error);
          $form.removeAttr('target');
          $iframe.remove();
        });
      };
    });
```

Server Side Edit Route:

```
// PUT edits
app.put('/users/:_id', function(req, res){
  var spokenLangs = req.body.spokenlanguages.split(',');
  var learnLangs = req.body.learninglanguages.split(',');
  var comms = req.body.commethod.split(',');
  var photos = []
  req.files.forEach(function(file, i){
    photos.push(req.files[i].path.replace('public/', '../'));
  });
  var updatedUser = new User(
    {
      username: req.body.username,
      firstName: req.body.fname,
      lastName: req.body.lname,
      age: req.body.age,
      gender: req.body.gender,
      spokenLanguages: spokenLangs,
      learningLanguages: learnLangs,
      info: req.body.info,
      country: req.body.country,
      city: req.body.city,
      comMethod: comms,
      photos: photos,
      lastLogin: Date.now()
    }
  );
  User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params._id, updatedUser, function(err, user){
    if(err){
      console.log('error updating user');
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      res.redirect('/matches');
    }
  });
});
```

Thank you good people!

Comment: Is your question "Should I use PUT or POST"?

Comment: Thanks for the question Tom. That wasn't my exact question, but if there's a clear answer to PUT or POST then that'd definitely be helpful! I used PUT in a different project to update comments, so I assumed it would also work for users, but I'm happy to be corrected if I'm wrong about that!

Comment: have you run through a debugger to see what triggers the 500 error?

Comment: Yeah, according to the Network tab in Chrome's dev tools, the error 500 is from trying to run a .forEach on the empty req.body object. Am I right in thinking that I should be using a PUT request to update the user account?